# Innosetup - reference a file from [Code] before the installation starts

Tags: installation, inno-setup, helpfile, context-sensitive-help

This is sort of a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658488/adding-a-help-button-to-an-innosetup-wizard-page).  I have a file that I want to include with my installation package (a .CHM help file) that I need to access during installation from code.  It doesn't need to be installed to the user's machine.  So I want to
- include the file in the installation package, probably uncompressed (so I guess I will do that with a `[Files] ... external` flag).
- reference the file during installation with code like:

```
procedure HelpButtonOnClick (Sender: TObject) ;   
var
    ErrorCode : Integer ;

begin
ShellExecAsOriginalUser ('open', ExpandConstant ('{???}') +  '\MyHelp.chm', '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end ;
```

So can I reference the file before installation starts - i.e. before any files are copied to the user machine?  How do I specify the path `ExpandConstant ('{???}')` to the file?  I have a help button on the wizard form that calls the above handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy. Just do

```
[Files]
Source: "MyHelp.chm"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

procedure HelpButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: integer;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('MyHelp.chm');
  ShellExecAsOriginalUser('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyHelp.chm'), '', '',
    SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;
```